# How to change the value of a Zend_Form_Element_Submit

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-form

I have several forms which the only difference is the text in the submit button.
I am trying to change the Submit text by changing it's value, but to no avail.

```
$form=getForm()//get a full Zend_Form object with elements.
$form->getElement('mySubmit')->setValue('new value');
....
....
$form->render(); //This will still put 'mySubmit' in the [submit] (var_dumping it shows the new value in the _value member, tried also with setAttrib();
```

And this one:

```
$form=getForm()//get a full with elements Zend_Form object.
$form->getElement('mySubmit')->setName('new value');
....
....
$form->render(); //This will still put 'newvalue' in the [submit] NO SPACES, no good :-(
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$form->getElement('mySubmit')->setLabel('new value')
```

Does this accomplish what you're looking for?

Comment: tnx! very intuitive attribute name :-)
Still wondering why the set value didn't work, might be a bug?